# Why I'm able to configure IP address on bridged interface?

Tags: ip, bridge

Consider following bridge setup:

```
brctl addbr mybridge
brctl addif mybridge eth0
```

I see a lot of people failing their setup on configuring the IP on *eth0* rather than the *mybridge* interface, so I was wondering why is it possible at all? Is there some case where IP on the interface would be actually useful? Or is that just nobody bothered to implement some safeguards there?

Comment: If you ever found an answer to your question, consider answering it for the benefit of others.

Comment: I've yet to see any reasonable use case for this. Which I think kinda answers the question - if there was some obvious use case for this it would probably pop up by now..